# Swift: How to Change UIButton Image on clicking submit button

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

I have four UIButtons which act as checkboxes, on tapping the button, the image changes. I have a submit button, where I perform a certain operation. My question is How do I change the image of the checkbox UIButton to normal and remove the data in textfield on clicking the submit button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@IBAction func submitActn(sender : UIButton!){

    checkBoxBtn.imageView?.image = UIImage(named: "image")  //Similar for every checkBtn
    textField1.text = ""
}
```

Or a much elegant way:-

Go to your **Storyboard** -> Select your buttons one at a time -> open Their **Attributes Inspector** ->

For *State Config* -Default, select a image in `image` box just below that you want to show as default(uncheck image )

For *State Config* -Selcted, select a image in `image` box just below that you want to show as when the button is selected(checked image)

```
@IBAction func submitActn(sender : UIButton!){

    checkBtn1.selected = false

    checkBtn2.selected = false

    checkBtn3.selected = false

    checkBtn4.selected = fasle

    textField1.text = ""
}
```

Comment: Thanks alot for the answer. I have accepted the answer, but  could not upvote because I dont have 15 reputation.